# Linq Lambda Expression to check null or empty

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Im new to Linq and Lambda expressions and I wanted to change this piece of code:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PictureUrl1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Picture2Url) &&
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Picture3Url) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Picture4Url) &&
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Picture5Url) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Picture6Url))
        return Content("");
```

Now I refactored that model to have an object with those properties and a list of said objects:

```
public class PublicInfoModelItem 
{
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

And the list:

```
public List<PublicInfoModelItem> ListOfImages = new List<PublicInfoModelItem>();
```

Model:

```
public class PublicInfoModel 
{
    public List<PublicInfoModelItem> ListOfImages = new List<PublicInfoModelItem>();

    public string Container { get; set; }

    public int TemplateId { get; set; }

    public PublicInfoModelItem InfoModelItem { get; set; }

}
```

And I was thinking a Lambda expression, something like:

```
    var result = model.ListOfImages.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PictureUrl)).ToList();
    if (result == null)
    {
        return Content("");
    }
```

I dont know if the above expression is correct or it could be improved.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the expression you posted, other than `ToList()` returning an empty list instead of null if there are no found `ListOfImages`.

Comment: result will never be `null`. Its `count` may be 0 though. If I understand your goal correctly, you can use `if(model.ListOfImages.All(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PictureUrl)))`

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use Any:

```
if (!model.ListOfImages.Any(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PictureUrl)))
{
    return Content("");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to append Brett`s solution:

```
if (!model.ListOfImages.Any(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PictureUrl)))
{
    return Content("");
}
```

Might be what you were looking for. But it is almost the same as:

```
if(model.ListOfImages.All(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PictureUrl)))
{
return Content("");
}
```

the only difference here is: `Any` will return on the first item that gets evaluated to true and `All` on the first which gets to false for the predicate. But since `All`'s predicate gets negated, it will occur at the same element in the list and will have the same result.

But `All` comes in handy when you want some more checking, for example:

```
if(model.ListOfImages.All(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PictureUrl) && x.PictureUrl.EndsWith(".jpg")))
{
return Content("");
}
```

Comment: This QA is another example of how we tend to overlook the little details. Both I and Brett got the answer the other way round! Including the upvotes, that's 5 of us that overlooked the mistake!

Comment: We're also looking at this in isolation of the rest of the code.  It might be more efficient to write "if any(isnullorempty()) do the other thing".  However, I should indeed have used "All" instead of "!Any" in my own answer as the intent is clearer.  I added the negation in rather a hurry to make it fit with the original question.  Guilty.

Comment: @Brett It's quite easy to make mistake with negation though. The equivalent construct of the OP code is `All(IsNullOrEmpty)`. If you want to use `Any`, you have to negate **both** the method and predicate, i.e. `!Any(!IsNullOrEmpty)`, which in this case is much harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find if a null/empty value **exists**. So another option would be to use `Exists()`:

```
if(model.ListOfImages.Exists(image => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PictureUrl)))
{
    return Content("");
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing `!`. Return must be if none of the values are null.

Comment: @Sach No the return must be if all of the values are null/empty. And so my answer is wrong because it'll return even if one of the value is null/empty 

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. I apply as follows:

```
var accionistas = repositorio.FindEntitySet<TBL_Accionista>(p => p.Estatus.Equals(1)).Select(a => new { a.Id_Accionista, Nombre = a.Apellido_Paterno + " " + a.Apellido_Materno + " " + a.Primer_Nombre, RazonSocial = String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Razon_Social)?string.Empty:a.Razon_Social, a.RFC });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to filter out some value:

```
var result = ListOfImages.Any(x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PictureUrl)) && (x.PictureUrl.Contains("text-to-filter")));
```